# Optimal DB structure for creating user segments

Tags: mysql, database, search, redis, nosql

I want to create a segmentation engine and can't seem to figure out the most optimal DB or DB structure to use for the task.
Currently I use MySQL as my primary DB, but the segmentation engine is a separate software component and thus can have a different DB if applicably.

Basically I have 10 million unique users identified with UserID (integer). Administrator of the Segmentation engine dynamically creates segments with some predefined rules (like age range, geolocation, transaction history etc.). Application should execute the rules of each segment periodically (once every 15 minutes) to get the current list of all users (can be upto 1 million users each) that belong to the segment and store it.

Later application is exposing the API to allow external systems use segmentation functionality, namely:
1. Get list of all segments that a particular UserID belongs to.
2. Get list of all UserIDs that a particular segment contains.

Note that because segments need to be updated very frequently (every 15 min) this causes massive transactions in DB to "maintain" the segments, where non-applicable users should be removed and new ones added all the time.

I have considered several approaches so far:
1. Plain MySQL where I have a table of users belonging to segments (SegmentID,UserID). (this approach has 2 drawbacks: storage space and constant delete/insert/update in MySQL which will degrade innodb performance by introducing page splitting).

2. Using JSON data types in MySQL, where I can have table (UserID,Segments), where segments is a json containing an array of SegmentIDs. (drawbacks here are slow search and slow updates)
3. Using Redis with Sets (UserID,Segments), where UserID will be the Key and Segments will be the Set of SegmentIDs. (drawbacks here are no simple way to search by SegmentID).

Has anyone worked with similar task and can provide any guidance?
Any feedback will be appreciated, so I can be pointed to a direction which I can further research.

Comment: Question is not clear. I can't imagine situation where segments of users change quickly beside a lot new users coming to database.

Comment: Let's say there is a segment of users who have made 10 transactions in last 24 hours (rolling period). This segment will change all the time.
Another example could be a segment of users who have logged in from mobile 5 times in last 24 hours (rolling period).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) for this task.

Comment: How optimal is ElasticSearch for storing multivalue fields consisting of 100,000 elements? In terms of maintaining (constant insert/update/delete of individual values in it) and indexing it?

Comment: Sorry, but i am not expert in ElasticSearch, i am software architect. I am sure it's can. But  better make another question here about ElasticSearch.

Comment: And follow you comment above you can  have a look at Hive and time series databases.